# How to find index of maximum value in array with missing field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here's a very simple data example below:

```py
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "uid": "0",
        "value": 0,
        
      },
      {
        "uid": "1",
        "value": 1,
        
      },
      {
        "uid": "2",
        "value": 2,
        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then, I want to find the corresponding `uid` of maximum `value`. In my case, the result should be `"2"`.

Here is the query I'm playing with:

```py
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "value_argmax": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$data.uid",
          {
            "$indexOfArray": [
              "$data.value",
              {
                "$max": "$data.value"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The code works find for my case. However, if there exists some missing fields, the query code may fail. For example, if I have a data example looks like below:

```py
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "uid": "0",
        // "value": 0, // missing field
        
      },
      {
        "uid": "1",
        "value": 1,
        
      },
      {
        "uid": "2",
        "value": 2,
        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The result of my query will be "1" instead of "2" (In my case, I just want to omit the missing field).

So, what should I do to fix my query?
Here's the simple test case: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8qiFRB8EsSE

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect when the max value exists more than once?

Comment: In that case, just return the corresponding `uid` of the `first` existing max value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$data",
               cond: { $eq: [{ $max: "$data.value" }, "$$this.value"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { value_argmax: { $first: "$data.uid" } } },
   { $unset: "data" }
])
```

Comment: Very nice solution, thank you! Just one question, what's the difference between `set` and `project` here? I find both are working fine.

Comment: `$project` shows specified fields and removes all other fields. `$set` (or alias `$addFields`) adds or update fields without touching any of the other ones. So, in your example it does not matter which one you use.

Comment: For people who uses the earlier version of MongoDB, you can use `arrayElemAt` with index 0 to replace `first`. Otherwise, it might cause a query error.